# XSL and how to remove duplicates

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an issue with writing xslt transformation. I want to show column with values from node:
Records/Record/PersonalData/PersonalDataDetail
Per each person under:
Root/Data/Response/Person

So I started with showing all values - code is below:

transformation.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
    <xsl:for-each select="Root/Data/Response/Person">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
      <td>
    <xsl:for-each select="Records/Record/PersonalData/PersonalDataDetail[(@title='Country1' or @title='Country2' or @title='Country3')]">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:element name="br"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transformation.xsl"?>

<Root>
    <Data>
        <Response>
            <Person>
                <Name>Robert A.</Name>
                <Records>
                    <Record>
                        <PersonalData>
                            <PersonalDataDetail title="Lucky Number">529</PersonalDataDetail>
                            <PersonalDataDetail title="Favorite Color">Blue</PersonalDataDetail>
                        </PersonalData>
                    </Record>
                </Records>
            </Person>
            <Person>
                <Name>Robert B.</Name>
                <Records>
                    <Record>
                        <PersonalData>
                            <PersonalDataDetail title="Lucky Number">3</PersonalDataDetail>
                            <PersonalDataDetail title="Country1">USA</PersonalDataDetail>
                        </PersonalData>
                    </Record>
                    <Record>
                        <PersonalData>
                            <PersonalDataDetail title="Favorite Color">Red</PersonalDataDetail>
                            <PersonalDataDetail title="Country2">UK</PersonalDataDetail>
                        </PersonalData>
                    </Record>
                    <Record>
                        <PersonalData>
                            <PersonalDataDetail title="Flight">AAA000</PersonalDataDetail>
                            <PersonalDataDetail title="Country2">UK</PersonalDataDetail>
                        </PersonalData>
                    </Record>
                </Records>
            </Person>
            <Person>
                <Name>Robert C.</Name>
                <Records>
                    <Record>
                        <PersonalData>
                            <PersonalDataDetail title="Lucky Number">529</PersonalDataDetail>
                            <PersonalDataDetail title="Country1">UK</PersonalDataDetail>
                        </PersonalData>
                    </Record>
                    <Record>
                        <PersonalData>
                            <PersonalDataDetail title="Country3">Argentina</PersonalDataDetail>
                        </PersonalData>
                    </Record>
                    <Record>
                        <PersonalData>
                            <PersonalDataDetail title="Country3">Argentina</PersonalDataDetail>
                            <PersonalDataDetail title="Flight">BBB000</PersonalDataDetail>
                        </PersonalData>
                    </Record>
                </Records>
            </Person>
        </Response>
    </Data>
</Root>
```

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyTAW.png)

Now I'm trying to remove duplicates, but only on person level.
I tried with changing for-each to:

Records/Record/PersonalData/PersonalDataDetail[**not(.=preceding::*)** and (@title='Country1' or @title='Country2' or @title='Country3')]

But it removes duplicates considering content of full document, not only for Person node.

Could you help me? I have to use XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred method to remove duplicates in XSLT 1.0 is [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). The complication in your case is that you only want to group within the ancestor `Person` element. This is solved by adding the unique id of the `Person` to the grouping key:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="country" match="PersonalDataDetail[starts-with(@title, 'Country')]" use="concat(., '|', generate-id(ancestor::Person))" />

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <xsl:for-each select="Data/Response/Person">
                    <xsl:variable name="person-id" select="generate-id()" />
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="Records/Record/PersonalData/PersonalDataDetail[starts-with(@title, 'Country')][count(. | key('country', concat(., '|', $person-id))[1]) = 1]">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                <br/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

That said, some XSLT 1.0 processors support the EXSLT `set:distinct()` extension function, which allows you to simplify the process to:

**XSLT 1.0 + EXSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
extension-element-prefixes="set">

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <xsl:for-each select="Data/Response/Person">
                    <xsl:variable name="person-id" select="generate-id()" />
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(Records/Record/PersonalData/PersonalDataDetail[starts-with(@title, 'Country')])">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                <br/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you! I use XSLT 1.0 solution and works. I don't know yet exactly what `[count(. | key('country', concat(., '|', $person-id))[1]) = 1]`. Could you describe it a little bit?

Comment: @Hostel It is described in the article I linked to.